# sequelize postgress bulk insert ignore if exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I have following code

```
await tbl.bulkCreate(response.data, {
                                ignoreDuplicates: true
                            });
```

in response.data there is array of object.

What I expect it should check all the fields found duplicate do not insert,
What I am think it working like if Id exist ignore

I Think this ignoreDuplicates is not working due to id field which is always new for new record

Is there anyway I can say that check certain fields if that exist do not insert else insert

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ignore duplicate values for primary keys? (not supported by MSSQL or Postgres < 9.5)
check your postgres version or you can use

```
{updateOnDuplicate : true}
```

try with composite key

```
queryInterface.addConstraint('Items', ['col1', 'col2'], {
  type: 'unique',
  name: 'custom_unique_constraint_name'
});
```

Comment: I need to check duplicate on other field, not on primary key

Comment: No, my case is I have 5 columns getting from another resource and I am using bulk insert those 5 columns, now in table I have one id column that is primary key with AI with other 5 columns. So if I make multiple request of another source IT keeps inserting as the id is being generated at time of insert and it is always new, and other 5 columns coming are duplicate, but due to new it insert in table duplicate records

Comment: you can define composite_key or find requested data with WHERE IN from raw Query and remove duplicate and then do bulkCreate . way with WHERE IN will be  easier one .
i Have a demo for the same if you want i can share .

Comment: I will be uploading millions of records with pagination, so manipulating this will be problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213850/discussion-between-vyas-arpit-and-md-parvez-alam).